# Can we duplicate the information in NFC TAGS

Tags: nfc

Can we duplicate the information? i mean:

i want to store a unique information in my tag(i want only one tag with unique information)

for example: boss having a tag ("my secured text")..

can employee do a same copy like("my secure text")in his tag?

AND IF boss's tag lost means how can he recreate the tag with same information ("my secure text")?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you do not want to have simple data storage tags (storing for example NDEF-formatted data). The data contents of such a simple tag can easily be copied from one tag to another. You should probably look into tags offering more sophisticated features such as authentication or encryption. An example of such a tag that is still affordable is the DESFire chip by NXP, see for feature description http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_card_ics/mifare_smart_card_ics/mifare_desfire/

To recreate a lost tag, you need to keep a backup of the information stored on it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use tagstand tasklauncher app to protect your data. The data in this software has 2 formats. one is for public, allowing all the user access it and the other is for private, which is stored in the local cellphone memory, and can be access only by the cellphone holder.

Wish this information may help you.